# translating curl_version() 24-bit version number to version string

Tags: php, curl

`curl_version()` returns (among other things) a 24-bit version number as well as the version string.  24-bit version number `463623` corresponds to string version `7.19.7`.

Is there a simple algorithm for converting the 24-bit version to the string?

Comment: The libcurl docs mention that "`version_num` is a 24 bit number created like this: <8 bits major number> | <8 bits minor number> | <8 bits patch number>. Version 7.9.8 is therefore returned as 0x070908." – the reverse conversion should just be a few bitmasks and shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this version number?

```
$v = curl_version();
echo $v['version']; # e.g. 7.15.5
```

It's easy to decipher:

```
$v = curl_version();
$n = $v['version_number'];
printf("%06x", $n); # e.g. 070f05
```

The version number is hex-decimal, 3 values, pick each one, convert to decimal:

```
   07: 7
   0f: 15
   05: 5
```

See: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/versions.html

Comment: He points out that it's returned. I think he wants an algorithm though.

Comment: @gms8994: That's likewise trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something in this spirit:

```
printf("%d.%d.%d", $version >> 16, ($version >>8)&0xff, $version & 0xff);
```